# Зачем вызываются методы QCamera.searchAndLock() и QCamera.unlock()?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

Блокировка всех поддерживаемых настроек камеры.

Для чего их необходимо блокировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказано в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html#searchAndLock-1)

> Locks the camera settings with the requested locks, including focusing
> in the single autofocus mode, exposure and white balance if the
> exposure and white balance modes are not manual.
>
> The camera settings are usually locked before taking one or multiple
> still images, in responce to the shutter button being half pressed.

**Перевод:** Блокирует настройки камеры, включая фокус, включая фокусировку в одиночном автофокусном режиме, экспозицию и баланс белого, если они не настраиваются вручную.

Настройки камеры обычно блокируются перед снимком кадра, или множества последовательных кадров в ответ на нажатие (в позицию pressed) кнопки затвора.

**Вывод:** Короче, чтобы зафиксировать настройки, чтобы они не изменялись во время съемки, если они автоматические.

**Unlock()** - обратная операция (кнопка затвора отжата - позиция release)